# Django request.user is anonymous in views without login_required decorator

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth

I am working on a Django (v2.0) app with django-allauth as auth backend. I'll explain my problem in steps:

1. User logs in -> user redirected to home page (can't access home page without login)
2. In the home page (after logging in), several calls are made for a particular view in the server.
   Ex: `https://mywebsite.com/api/getstuff/123`
3. **Problem:** `getstuff` returns/prints data that is intended for a user who is NOT logged in.

`getstuff` is defined in urls.py as:

`url(r'^api/getstuff/(?P<hash_code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})$', views.getstuff, name='getstuff')`

in views.py: (`views.getstuff`)

```
@csrf_protect
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def getstuff(request,hash_code):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #do stuff....
        print('user is authenticated!')
        return HttpResponse(hash_code+'foo-auth')
    else:
        #do other stuff..
        print('user is NOT authenticated')
        return HttpResponse(hash_code+'foo-un_auth')
```

I only see `user is NOT authenticated` being printed in my case. Shouldn't the output be `user is authenticated` since the user is already logged in? the `request.user` object is an AnonymousUser object. All the requests I make are from `https`.

few configurations from settings.py:

```
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True #tried removing this, still same result as above

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'mysite.core',
    'bootstrapform',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'embed',
    'channels',
    'djcelery'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

I tried clearing cache before accessing the website and logging in - still same result.
Am I missing something? What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you making the request to `getstuff` using ajax? If so, show that code. There's nothing wrong with the `getstuff` view in your question.

Comment: check your browser cookie is there a sessionid after login ? how do you login post login view code

Comment: @NaqibHakimi yes, there is a sessionid after login. Looks something like this: `"c2508310f74ded11dc9cce0698232db38a26c217$[[\"__json_message\"\0540\05425\054\"Successfully signed in as foobar.\"]]"`. The login is handled by django-allauth. I have not modified it or overridden it by any custom class.

Comment: @Alasdair It is not an ajax call, I've abstracted what happens inside getstuff to explain the problem in a simple way. What getstuff actually does is, it returns something like the following IF the user is authenticated (i.e as a part of #do stuff...): return HttpResponse(item_content, content_type="image/png",status=200) This is called just as a link in the src attribute of a img tag. Ex: <img src = "https://mywebsite.com/api/getstuff/123"> But the problem here is the request.user - which says the user is NOT authenticated even after login.

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way around. The check `if request.user.is_authenticated:` is fine. If that evaluates to `False`, then the request is not authenticated, either because the login failed, or the logged in session details were not sent with the request. Why do you have `mywebsite.com/` in `src="mywebsite.com/api/getstuff/123"`? If you are accessing the image on another domain then you won't be logged in on that domain.

Comment: add SITE_ID = 1 in settings and in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS add  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', ..... then go to admin page and login from there .

Comment: @Alasdair  *faceplam*...its my fault...you are right... it should have been `"/api/getstuff/123"`. Just tried and it works fine. There is nothing wrong with any of my backend code for this. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @NaqibHakimi `SITE_ID` isn't always 1 (for ex, my site runs on 2), it really depends on your project. I can't add django's auth backend because as I mentioned in the question, all my views use allauth backend. The problem is not with django, but with a simple HTML syntax as @Alasdair pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `if request.user.is_authenticated:` is fine. Change the image `src` tag to use the domain that you logged into.

```
<img src="/api/getstuff/123">
```

Comment: Before I solved it using your answer, I tried this on different browsers.  It did not work on IE Edge, Chrome, BUT it was working fine in Firefox. Weird. Any idea why?  (by working I mean in firefox, `<img src="mywebsite.com/api/getstuff/123">` DID fetch the image and the request.user object was the logged in user)

Comment: I don't know why the browsers would behave differently. You could compare the `request` for different browsers (e.g. session and cookies) to see what varies between the browsers.